# Combining Javascript objects

Tags: javascript

I am creating a food menu app using reactjs at the frontend and django backend. I unfortunately got stuck here mostly because of my little knowledge of Javascript.Here is my problem. I have this array of objects

```
const objectOfArray = [
    {
    "id":"1a2f2c7a-0e06-4784-a1fb-68e083a72aa5","cat_id":"812347b3-615f-4f4a-b201-64737ddf4718","event_id":"ead9898c-9606-49e0-aa2b-c7f34331a856"
    },
    {
    "id":"7bee12ac-7253-4e5a-a86f-2ea0a3765541","cat_id":"6968da9d-4475-4431-801d-e3eeda02145a","event_id":"ead9898c-9606-49e0-aa2b-c7f34331a856"
    },
    {
    "id":"42763c0d-84f1-4f07-97c8-aa914bfb92fa","cat_id":"812347b3-615f-4f4a-b201-64737ddf4718","event_id":"ead9898c-9606-49e0-aa2b-c7f34331a856"
    }
]
```

then another object `const myObject = {"seat":"4","table":"10"}`

I want each of the object in **objectOfArray** to have **myObject** so that the output now looks like this

```
[
    {
    "id":"1a2f2c7a-0e06-4784-a1fb-68e083a72aa5","cat_id":"812347b3-615f-4f4a-b201-64737ddf4718","event_id":"ead9898c-9606-49e0-aa2b-c7f34331a856","seat":"4","table":"10"
    },
    {
    "id":"7bee12ac-7253-4e5a-a86f-2ea0a3765541","cat_id":"6968da9d-4475-4431-801d-e3eeda02145a","event_id":"ead9898c-9606-49e0-aa2b-c7f34331a856","seat":"4","table":"10"
    },
    {
    "id":"42763c0d-84f1-4f07-97c8-aa914bfb92fa","cat_id":"812347b3-615f-4f4a-b201-64737ddf4718","event_id":"ead9898c-9606-49e0-aa2b-c7f34331a856","seat":"4","table":"10"
    }
]
```

Comment: `expected = objectOfArray.map(v => ({...v, ...myObject}))`

Comment: Please look at your post after submitting, so you can tell whether you have any markup errors. Which you do. [And you should fix](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Look into .map()

Answer (score 1):

As Lawrence [suggested in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69502884/combining-javascript-objects/69502995#comment122848564_69502884) you can accomplish this using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
const objectOfArray = [
    {
    "id":"1a2f2c7a-0e06-4784-a1fb-68e083a72aa5","cat_id":"812347b3-615f-4f4a-b201-64737ddf4718","event_id":"ead9898c-9606-49e0-aa2b-c7f34331a856"
    },
    {
    "id":"7bee12ac-7253-4e5a-a86f-2ea0a3765541","cat_id":"6968da9d-4475-4431-801d-e3eeda02145a","event_id":"ead9898c-9606-49e0-aa2b-c7f34331a856"
    },
    {
    "id":"42763c0d-84f1-4f07-97c8-aa914bfb92fa","cat_id":"812347b3-615f-4f4a-b201-64737ddf4718","event_id":"ead9898c-9606-49e0-aa2b-c7f34331a856"
    }
]

const myObject = {"seat":"4","table":"10"};

const result = objectOfArray.map(item => ({...item, ...myObject}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the properties in `myObject` to some other object with [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

You also need a way to iterate over the original array: [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) will do that.

Combining these two, you get

```js
const objectOfArray = [
        {
            "id":"1a2f2c7a-0e06-4784-a1fb-68e083a72aa5","cat_id":"812347b3-615f-4f4a-b201-64737ddf4718","event_id":"ead9898c-9606-49e0-aa2b-c7f34331a856"
        },
        {
            "id":"7bee12ac-7253-4e5a-a86f-2ea0a3765541","cat_id":"6968da9d-4475-4431-801d-e3eeda02145a","event_id":"ead9898c-9606-49e0-aa2b-c7f34331a856"
        },
        {
            "id":"42763c0d-84f1-4f07-97c8-aa914bfb92fa","cat_id":"812347b3-615f-4f4a-b201-64737ddf4718","event_id":"ead9898c-9606-49e0-aa2b-c7f34331a856"
        }
    ];

const myObject = {"seat":"4","table":"10"}

newArray = objectOfArray.map(e=>Object.assign(e,myObject));

console.log(newArray);
```